# Sitecore with Oracle Commerce/ATG 11.3 and Endeca

Tags: oracle, sitecore8, endeca

Can anyone advice if is it possible Sitecore would work with  Oracle Commerce/ATG 11.3 and Endeca?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why it can't be integrated, it depends how deeply you want to integrate it. For example SiteCore exposes a [RESTful API](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_restful_api_for_the_itemservice) that allows you to get to individual content items.

Since you mention Endeca as well, I assume you want to be able to index the content too? For that you will probably have to develop your own CAS connector, potentially hooking in to the SiteCore search functionality.

There may be other APIs to hook into as well but since your question is whether it is possible. The answer is still 'Yes'.

As for whether it is the right solution, that is a different question. What does SiteCore give you that the BCC doesn't? Can you migrate from SiteCore to the BCC? Does SiteCore expose other APIs that will allow them to be 'read-only' stores in an ATG application (BCC or Storefront)? Many options exist.